# Calling Google Drive API using Ruby on Rails Framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api, drive

I am trying to get this code to work which is mentioned as example on Google-auth-library-ruby

```
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/web_user_authorizer'
require 'googleauth/stores/redis_token_store'
require 'redis'

client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('/path/to/client_secrets.json')
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::RedisTokenStore.new(redis: Redis.new)
authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(
  client_id, scope, token_store, '/oauth2callback')


get('/authorize') do
    # NOTE: Assumes the user is already authenticated to the app
    user_id = request.session['user_id']
    credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id, request)
    if credential`enter code here`s.nil?
        redirect authorizer.get_authorization_url(login_hint: user_id,         request: request)
   end
       # Credentials are valid, can call APIs
       # ...
end

get('/oauth2callback') do
    target_url = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.handle_auth_callback_deferred(
    request)
    redirect target_url
end
```

in the get '/authorize' method is always nil even the user is logged in and authenticated using Devise Gem and Google Oauth2 gem .

Can anyone may be share an example in rails framework how to obtain subsequent authorizations from Google to access any of their apis for which the user has given consent

Even the ruby methods used on the Google website seems to have been deprecated so not finding much information online

Thank you in advance

Comment: Based from the document [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ruby), try using `def` instead of `get`. This is also how the samples in the [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/tree/master/samples/cli) are coded. I think these codes are up to date because they are updated 5 months ago. Hope this helps.

Comment: The sample code mentioned on google works fine if it is a normal local system ruby program. But the place where i am confused is how to implement it in rails as if i follow the sample code  from github before requesting authorisation the code assumes that user is already authenticated and uses the following line   user_id = request.session['user_id'] .I am not able to understand how to obtain this user id as for me the request.session['user_id'] is always nil although the user is signed in using Devise and Google OmniAuth2

Comment: @Anand hi there - did you manage to get it working? I am myself struggling on this would appreciate very much if you posted your code sample.

Comment: I have followed the instructions in this link https://readysteadycode.com/howto-integrate-google-calendar-with-rails . Hopefully it would be help you. Let me know if any issues

Comment: @BKSpurgeon have you managed to get it working or else let me know so that i can send you the code

Comment: @Anand I've got it working (just) but there will be someone in the future who will come by this thread who might need it - perhaps for their benefit?

Comment: sure. I am myself still working and learning to get the hang of Google API interaction with Rails. Will definitely write a post and place the link here. Thank you for the suggestion